# Validating every textbox for every single textbox to be INT in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

Hi i searched online for this code

```
        con.Open();
        int parsedValue;
        if (!int.TryParse(txtCCL.Text, out parsedValue))// if not an integer return message below
        {
            MessageBox.Show("This is a number only field");
            return;
        }
        else
        {
        }
```

like in the txtCCL.Text how do i call check multiple textboxes like

```
        con.Open();
        int parsedValue;
        if (!int.TryParse(txtCCL.Text||txtA.text||txtB.text, out parsedValue))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("This is a number only field");
            return;
        }
        else
        {
        }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to iterate all the text boxes.

`TryParse` can not take multiple text boxes as input.

```
    //LOOP ALL CONTROLS AND FIND TEXT BOXES
    foreach (TextBox txtBox in this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
    {
       int number;

       bool result = Int32.TryParse(txtBox.Text, out number);

       if (result)
       {
           //PRINT TEXT BOX NAME WHICH CAN BE CONVERTIBLE
           MessageBox.Show(txtBox.Name + " is a number only field");
       }
    }
```

Comment: Hi i tried this code and i tried running it with an else condition but it still goes to the else condition...

Comment: Does your text boxes have values. I mean, do they have numbers in any of the text boxes

Comment: Yes they have values but i want to validate if the value is not an integer if not it would go to the else condition(which is the normal function)

Comment: If you want to check if not integer, then your if statement should be if(!result). Int32.TryParse returns true if the parsing is successful . The parsing will be be successful, if the text box has a number.

Comment: Disadvantage here is you can not tell specifically check these textboxes, you can have INT text boxes for the form and no any other data type

Answer (score 0):

You can use TryParse method with if condition with multiple check

```
int v1;
    if (int.TryParse(txtCCL.Text, out v1) && int.TryParse(txt2.Text,out v1) && int.TryParse(txt3.Text,out v1))
    {
            //is integer
    }
```

Comment: your answer works too but i only can put one correct answer sorry

Comment: Yes the other answer validates all text box too but in a loop which i find is more efficient

Comment: @user8719124 can not use ||  sorry, it must && to check all for validate

Comment: i checked in the code when it is && it goes to the else loop for the 2nd condition... when i use || it validates all... Because the condition is if the value is not an integer but if you put && it will only happen if all are not integers.. mistake on my part when setting the question too...

Comment: You have to check all text box contain INT right, for that you have to use ANd, other wise if only one contain INT and other not, condition will true

Comment: Yes, All must be INT  to true the criteria, according to your question you need that

Comment: your question is this "Validating multiple textbox at once in c# ", that means all text box must contain INT

Comment: My bad i changed the question already so if any of the boxes are not INT it will show the message

Comment: Same thing, no change...  my If works all TRUE, if one failed it goes to else

Comment: oh wait sorry i see wrongly my bad did not see u changed all to int.tryparse because mine was !int.tryparse